# Gráfico de barras - ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

Tenho um data-frame com a estrutura abaixo. Quero fazer um gráfico de barras simples que relacione o "CID" por tipo (A, B, C, etc...) com os dias de afastamento e outro com os Atendimentos.

```
df <- data.frame(CID = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "Z"),
              AFASTAMENTOS = c(2,3,5,8,9, 12),
              ATENDIMENTOS = c(21, 32, 4, 6, 7, 43),
              stringAsfactors = FALSE )
```

Tentei com o ggplot2, fazendo a variável CID como um fator:

```
ggplot(df, aes(CID, y = AFASTAMENTOS)) + geom_bar()
```

Que me retornou:
    Error: stat_count() must not be used with a y aesthetic.

Muito obrigado,

Comment: Seu código, infelizmente, não é reproduzível. Teria como, por favor, disponibilizar uma parte deste data frame? Se tu manjar de inglês, o stackoverflow gringo tem um texto muito bom sobre como fazer um post minimamente reproduzível: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5963610/1027912

Answer (score 2):

Tente isto:

```
df <- data.frame(CID = c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C", "Z"),
                 AFASTAMENTOS = c(2,3,5,8,9, 12),
                 ATENDIMENTOS = c(21, 32, 4, 6, 7, 43),
                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE )
# acumular por CID
dfc<-data.frame(do.call(rbind,by(data = df[,-1],INDICES = df$CID,FUN = colSums)))
dfc$CID<-rownames(dfc)
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
  df.long<-melt(dfc,id.vars="CID") # formatar para long
  ggplot(df.long,aes(x=CID,y=value,fill=factor(variable)))+
    geom_bar(stat="identity",position="dodge")+
    scale_fill_discrete(name="Procedimento")+
    ylab("Número")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2):

O seu erro acontece porque o `ggplot` foi desenhado para trabalhar com bases em formato long. Em que cada linha é uma observação. No seu caso os dados já estão agregados por CID. Por isso, você precisa especificar o argumento `stat = "identity"`. Por padrão o `ggplot` usa `count` e conta quantas linhas possuem cada um dos CID.

O meu código faz a mesma coisa que o do Robert, mas ao meu ver é mais intuitivo. Nós dois transformamos os dados para o formato long para se aproveitar da facilidade de fazer legendas no ggplot dessa forma.

```
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)
df %>%
  gather(Procedimento, Qtd, - CID) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = CID, y = Qtd, fill = Procedimento)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]