# grafico de barras para multiplas variaveis entre grupos

Tags: r, ggplot2, gráfico, barplot, gráfico-de-dispersão

Olá, preciso criar um grafico de barras semelhante a esse:
[Gráfico de barras - ggplot2](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/145794/gr%C3%A1fico-de-barras-ggplot2), porém com as bolinhas referentes a cada ponto de dado.
semelhante a esse:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

porém preciso que multiplas variáveis sejam apresentadas no mesmo grafico, para ambos os grupos.

dados exemplos:

```
dados <- data.frame(   grupos = c( 1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),  
 ECT = c(21, 35, 41, 23, 13, 17, 18, 16, 34, 37, 35, 18, 12, 9, 22,21), 
 DG = c(31, 35, 21, 23, 33, 17, 18, 16, 34, 27, 15, 28, 22, 29, 32,34),  
 CA3 = c(11, 15, 11, 13, 13, 17, 18, 16, 14, 17, 15, 18, 12, 19, 12,10),
 D2= c(12, 16, 12, 14, 10, 15, 20, 20, 10, 19, 14, 12, 12, 12, 14 ,9) )
```

essa é a rotina que estou usando para gerar o gráfico com uma unica variável entre grupos:
require(ggplot2)

```
    ### Ploto uma variável por grupo

p1<-ggplot(dados, aes(x = grupos, y = ECT, fill=grupos )) +
  geom_bar(stat = "summary", fun = "mean", alpha=0.5) +
  geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1)) +
  geom_jitter(width = (0.25)) +
  labs(y = "c-fos expression", x = "areas") +
    theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
        legend.position = "none", )
```

O meu código é limitado, pois quero todas as variáveis (DG, ECT, CA3) plotadas juntas no mesmo gráfico, por grupo.

Além disso queria fazer a plotagem de todas as correação de cada variável por grupo com a variavel D2, colocando a estatistica da correlação no gráfico.

Eu fiz o gráfico mas não estou conseguindo colocar a estatistica nele.

```
IMUNOAI<-subset(dados,grupos=="1")
IMUNOBI<-subset(dados,grupos=="2")

ggplot(IMUNOAI) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ECT, y = D2, color = "AI")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = ECT, y = D2)) 

ggplot(IMUNOBI) +
  geom_point(aes(x = ECT, y = D2, color = "AI")) + 
  geom_smooth(method = lm, aes(x = ECT, y = D2))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score 1):

Para o grafico com multiplas variaveis resolvi o problema:
primeiro apliquei a função melted para mesclar todas as variaveis em uma coluna e seus valores em outra coluna.

```
library(reshape2) #carrega o pacote
 aibi_melted <- melt(dados, id.vars=c("grupos")) #mescla todas as variaveis de interesse entre grupos
 colnames(aibi_melted)[2] <- "areas" # atribuo nome a coluna com as variaveis
 
 aibi_melted$grupos <- as.factor(aibi_melted$grupos)  #modifico a variavel de grupo como um fator
 
 ggplot(aibi_melted, aes(x = areas, y = value, color = grupos)) +
   geom_bar(position = position_dodge(1),stat = "summary", fun = "mean", alpha=0.5) +
   geom_errorbar(stat = "summary", fun.data = "mean_sdl", fun.args = list(mult=1))+ 
   geom_jitter(width = (0.25), size=0.4) +
   labs(y = "c-fos expression", x = "areas") +
   theme(axis.title = element_text(size = 10, face = "bold"),
         legend.position = "none" )
```

Resolvido, assim consigo ter todas as variaveis dentro do mesmo plot com pontos.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ainda falta resolver o gráfico de disperção.

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Comunidade veja a edição que fiz

Comment: @AnaPaulaCastro Sugestão: em vez de `color = grupos` use `fill = grupos`.